# Mystery echo - can't find why

Tags: php, echo

So I've made this upload script and to make it more secure, I'm finding out the type of each file.

However, for some reason, the filetype is being echoed back to me!
For example:

> image/jpeg; charset=binary Please upload only SWF files!

The echoed string looks same when the upload is successful.

The code:

```
 <?php session_start();
defined('IN_SCRIPT') ? NULL : define('IN_SCRIPT', NULL);
require_once 'inc/db_connect.php';
require_once 'styles/import.php';
$style = new style_class(NULL);
if(!isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) || empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) die($style->upload_no_parameter());

$filetype = system('file -bi '.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$filetype = explode(';', $filetype, 1);
if ($filetype[0] != 'application/x-shockwave-flash; charset=binary') die($style->upload_wrong_format());


$sha256 = hash_file("sha256", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM swf WHERE hash = :hash');
$result = $query->execute(array(':hash'=>$sha256));

if ($query->rowCount() != 0) die($style->upload_duplicate());

$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM swf ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;');
$name = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$new_name = 'uploads/'.($name['id']+1).'.swf';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $new_name)) { 
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO swf (uploader, upload_time, hash) VALUES (:id, NOW(), :hash);');
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['id'], ':hash'=> $sha256));
    echo $style->upload_success();
    }
else
    echo $style->upload_fail();
?>
```

I can't see why the script would do such echo...

Thank you!

EDIT:

The style_class was the first place where I looked. This class contains functions returning mainly HTML text. The whole class is auto-generated from database.

I'm copying here the upload_* from the generated file, so you can see:

```
class style_class{
    function upload_no_parameter(){
        echo "<b>All parameters must be set!</b>";
    }
    function upload_fail(){
        echo "<b>There was an error, please try again.</b>";
    }
    function upload_success(){
        echo "<b>Your SWF has been uploaded!</b>";
    }
    function upload_duplicate(){
        echo "<b>File already exists!</b>";
    }
    function upload_wrong_format(){
        echo "<b>Please upload only SWF files!</b>";
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because your have "if ($filetype[0] != 'application/x-shockwave-flash; charset=binary') die($style->upload_wrong_format())" and it isn't?

Comment: Show us the `style_class` definition

Comment: You have many `die()` calls and an `echo` call at the end - one of these is printing the specified text... I'm almost sure the text is then defined in Your `style_class` class.

Comment: why not check by `die("i am here");`

Comment: why exec() out to file, when you could use [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) instead?

Comment: Updated the question. Provided you the style_class code.

Comment: What if you replace all the `echo` in your `style_class` with `return` statements?

Comment: @cheesemacfly then the page is blank :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet `die($style->upload_wrong_format())` is causing the issue. Check that function.

Comment: It can't be this. The echo occurs even when this function isn't called. (When the upload is successful)

Comment: @ChrisIllusion that's because you have this too `echo $style->upload_success();`. Edit your question and post the `style_class` code.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some very nasty logic bugs in your code:

1) Assuming the file upload succeeded. Proper error handling goes like this:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("File upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

Checking any of the other fields in any file upload is not proper - those fields can still be present and populated even for a failed upload. The error codes are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

2) you're using `exec()` and calling `file` to determine mimetypes. Why? PHP has the `finfo` library for just this purpose: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php  it uses the same magic numbers library as `file` and doesn't require an exec() call to work.

3) You have a very racey error-prone method of getting an ID number for your swf:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM swf ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;');
$name = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$new_name = 'uploads/'.($name['id']+1).'.swf';
```

Nothing says that another script cannot execute AND complete in the time you fetch this ID number and the time you complete thigns here. A proper method is to start a transaction, insert a skeleton record into the DB, retrieve its auto_increment primary key, then update the record and do your file moves with that id. It'll be guaranteed to be unique, whereas at some point your code WILL fail and stomp on another upload.

Comment: because you're telling it to. Have you verified that what you get out of the explode() call is EXACTLY what you're comparing against in the string? There may be a hidden character (e.g. linefeed) at the end of the string that you're not checking for. If you use finfo(), none of that would be relevant - you'd just get a mime string and nothing else.